# How to identify build architecture from packages?

Tags: linux, build

I have a machine with Red Hat AS5. On it are installed two versions of a linux application called xmlsec. One is supposedly built for AS3 and the other, AS5. Is there any way to verify which is which? The file names provide this information but is there a way to look into the signature of the installed package to ensure accuracy?

In general, is there a way to determine the build architecture (OS) of a completed installation?

Let me know if I need to provide more information.

I'm still new to building and maintaining packages. Please direct me to some books or websites if my question doesn't make sense or I just need to gain more understanding.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

How about it?

```
$rpm -q -a --queryformat='%{N}-%{V}-%{R}.%{arch}\n'
vsftpd-2.0.1-5.EL4.5.x86_64
hal-0.4.2-6.EL4.x86_64
```

Or Try this one

```
$rpm -q -a --queryformat '%{NAME}%{VERSION}%{RELEASE}\n'
xorg-x11-twm6.8.21.EL.18
hwbrowser0.190.EL4.4
```

Buildarch tag

```
$rpm -q --queryformat='%{N}-%{V}-%{R}.%{arch}.%{BUILDARCHS}\n' rpm
rpm-4.4.2.3-18.el5.x86_64.(none)
```

List of tags

```
$rpm --querytags
BUILDHOST
OS
POSTIN
POSTUN
FILELINKTOS
BUILDTIME
BUILDHOST
BUILDARCHS
```

Comment: Thanks. What if I do not have an RPM for it? e.g. they were installed from source and no RPMs were created.

Comment: No, you can't find any info from source compile apps.